# Multiple definition of function error wont go away

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a project with many files and they all include one header called logging.h, I dont  know what happened but for some reason when i try to compile this happens. I can not revert the changes and I dont know what to do.

These lines repeat themselves multiple times

```
/usr/bin/ld: fs/operations.o: in function `send_request':
/root/so/mbroker/utils/logging.h:59: multiple definition of `send_request'; mbroker/mbroker.o:/root/so/mbroker/utils/logging.h:59: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: fs/operations.o: in function `serialize':
/root/so/mbroker/utils/logging.h:68: multiple definition of `serialize'; mbroker/mbroker.o:/root/so/mbroker/utils/logging.h:68: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: fs/state.o: in function `clear_session':
/root/so/mbroker/utils/logging.h:53: multiple definition of `clear_session'; mbroker/mbroker.o:/root/so/mbroker/utils/logging.h:53: first defined here
```

As you can see it's all happening in logging.h

Here's my logging.h

```
#ifndef __UTILS_LOGGING_H__
#define __UTILS_LOGGING_H__

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> //open
#include <fcntl.h>  //flags for open
#include <unistd.h>

#define PIPENAME 256
#define BOXNAME 32
#define MSIZE 256
#define COMMAND 8

static const __uint8_t REGISTER_PUBLISHER = 1;
static const __uint8_t REGISTER_SUBSCRIBER = 2;
static const __uint8_t CREATE_BOX = 3;
static const __uint8_t REMOVE_BOX = 5;
static const __uint8_t LIST_BOX = 7;

static const char INVALID_SESSIONS[] = "Invalid number of sessions";
static const char PIPENAME_TOO_BIG[] = "The pipe's name has too many characters";
static const char INVALID_BOXNAME[] = "The box's name is invalid";
static const char INVALID_NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS[] = "Insufficient or too many arguments";
static const char INVALID_ARGUMENTS[] = "One of the arguments is invalid";
static const char UNEXISTENT_PIPE[] = "Pipe doesn't exist";
static const char EXISTENT_PIPE[] = "Pipe already exists";
static const char ERROR_WRITING_PIPE[] = "Error writing to pipe";
static const char SIGNAL_FAIL[] ="Failed to initialize signals";

typedef struct box{
    char boxname[BOXNAME];
    int hasWriter;
    int n_readers;
    struct box *next;
} box;

typedef struct req{
    int _code;
    char _client_pipe[PIPENAME];
    char _box_name[BOXNAME];
} request;

typedef enum {
    LOG_QUIET = 0,
    LOG_NORMAL = 1,
    LOG_VERBOSE = 2,
} log_level_t;

//deletes fifo
void clear_session(int fd, char* fn){
    close(fd);
    unlink(fn);
}

/*writes to pipe tx a pointer with information*/
void send_request(int tx, request *r1) {
    ssize_t ret = write(tx, &r1, sizeof(r1)); 
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "ERROR: %s\n", ERROR_WRITING_PIPE);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/*Returns a pointer to a struct containing the request*/
request *serialize(int code, char* client_pipe, char* box_name){
    request *r1 = (request*) malloc(sizeof(request));
    r1->_code  = code;
    strcpy(r1->_client_pipe, client_pipe); 
    strcpy(r1->_box_name, box_name); 
    return r1;
}
void sig_handler(int sig);

void set_log_level(log_level_t level);
extern log_level_t g_level;

#define INFO(...)                                                              \
    do {                                                                       \
        char buf[2048];                                                        \
        snprintf(buf, 2048, __VA_ARGS__);                                      \
        fprintf(stderr, "[INFO]:  %s:%d :: %s :: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__,    \
                __func__, buf);                                                \
    } while (0);

#define PANIC(...)                                                             \
    do {                                                                       \
        char buf[2048];                                                        \
        snprintf(buf, 2048, __VA_ARGS__);                                      \
        fprintf(stderr, "[PANIC]: %s:%d :: %s :: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__,    \
                __func__, buf);                                                \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                    \
    } while (0);

#define WARN(...)                                                              \
    do {                                                                       \
        if (g_level == LOG_NORMAL || g_level == LOG_VERBOSE) {                 \
            char buf[2048];                                                    \
            snprintf(buf, 2048, __VA_ARGS__);                                  \
            fprintf(stderr, "[WARN]:  %s:%d :: %s :: %s\n", __FILE__,          \
                    __LINE__, __func__, buf);                                  \
        }                                                                      \
    } while (0);

#define LOG(...)                                                               \
    do {                                                                       \
        if (g_level == LOG_NORMAL || g_level == LOG_VERBOSE) {                 \
            char buf[2048];                                                    \
            snprintf(buf, 2048, __VA_ARGS__);                                  \
            fprintf(stderr, "[LOG]:   %s:%d :: %s :: %s\n", __FILE__,          \
                    __LINE__, __func__, buf);                                  \
        }                                                                      \
    } while (0);

#define DEBUG(...)                                                             \
    do {                                                                       \
        if (g_level == LOG_VERBOSE) {                                          \
            char buf[2048];                                                    \
            snprintf(buf, 2048, __VA_ARGS__);                                  \
            fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG]: %s:%d :: %s :: %s\n", __FILE__,          \
                    __LINE__, __func__, buf);                                  \
        }                                                                      \
    } while (0);

#endif // __UTILS_LOGGING_H__
```

I tried deleting files, going back as far as i could but this error wont stop haunting me.
I also tried make clean multiple times, but did nothing either.

I went back to an old backup of the project which was ok and now it's showing me this same error message again. I tried compiling both through vsc and through wsl.

Now that i think it through, the error might have started when i included .c in another file. I have long deleted that include line but am still getting the errors.

Comment: Because you *define* (implement) the functions in the header file, and that header file is (I assume) included into multiple [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Either define them as `static` or `inline`, or only *declare* the functions in the header file, and define the functions in a single source file.

Comment: Unrelated: If you `#include <stdint.h>` you can use the standard typedef `uint8_t` instead of `__uint8_t`.

Comment: Copy the functions currently defined in logging.h into a .c file, e.g. logging.c. Convert the existing functions defined in logging.h into function declarations.

Comment: @IanAbbott thank you so much this was such a simple mistake I dont know why it only complained now!

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved only writing prototypes on the header and implementing the functions in a logging.c. It's weird the compiler only warned me after like many and many trials, but it's solved and that's all i could ask for.